# How to do a recyclerview on a viewpager from a asynchronous HTTP post

Tags: android, android-studio, kotlin, android-recyclerview, android-viewpager

Currently designing an app in Kotlin, effectivelly needs to have two different areas that can be swiped between that use database results.

So to do this right now I'm using a viewpager connected to 2 fragments, fragment1 is working perfectly because I can populate it from my mainactivity and because it's just using some TextViews.

Fragment 2 however is populated by a recyclerview with a variable number of items.

Both of these come from a async HTTP Post that sends to our website, coming out correctly as a string in the format "45,1,5,7" for example which I'm then converting into an ArrayList in Kotlin.

The problem seems to be getting this array to fragment 2 before swiping to it.

I've been trying the past few days going through different solutions but I'm not really able to get the input from any of these.

I've also tried putting the adapter call inside the Async function itself but it doesn't display any of the fragments when I do that.

The only thing that yielded the correct results so far was to put a second post request inside the fragment2 itself, however this only worked after swiping on it and didn't do it straight away either so isn't really viable for what I'm after.

Code has more than just this in it, so only going to show the relevent parts.

Main Activity oncreate(stripped alot):

```
    @Override
    override fun onCreate(savedInstanceState: Bundle?) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState)


        window.decorView.systemUiVisibility = SYSTEM_UI_FLAG_FULLSCREEN

        actionBar?.hide()

        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main)



        grabtraps() // Effectivelly where the Async function is done

        val adapter = MyViewPagerAdapter(supportFragmentManager)
        adapter.addFragment(fragment_1() , " One ")
        adapter.addFragment(Fragment2() , " Two ")
        //     adapter.addFragment(FragmentThree() , " Three ")
        //     adapter.addFragment(FragmentFour() , " Four ")
        vpPager.adapter = adapter

        val tabs2 = findViewById<TabLayout>(R.id.tabs);
        tabs2.setupWithViewPager(vpPager)

// Like I said earlier, tried this inside the function but didn't show up in general.


    }
```

Grabtraps() - still in MainActivity - I've stripped alot of the stuff relating to fragment1 since that's working

```
    fun grabtraps(){


        val sharedPref: SharedPreferences = getSharedPreferences(PREF_NAME, PRIVATE_MODE)

        val username = sharedPref.getString("user", "Not logged in")

        val jsoncode = JSONObject()
        jsoncode.put("username", username)

// Basically getting username into the HTTPS Post, PHP pics it up on the otherside

        "https://fakesite.com/gettraps.php".httpPost()
                .header("Content-Type", "application/json")
                .body(jsoncode.toString())
                .response{
                    request, response, result ->
                    when (result) {

                        is Result.Failure -> {

// Can probably skip this side - occurs if fails to connect.

                            mResultTextView = findViewById(R.id.result_textview)



                            var inputto = sharedPref.getString("user", "Please Log in")
                            if(inputto != "Please Log in"){
                                inputto = "Welcome, $inputto"
                            }
                            mResultTextView.text = inputto


                        }
                        is Result.Success -> {

                            val output = String(response.data)

                            val delimiter = ","

                            val parts = output.split(delimiter)

// Effectivelly just the output then put into an ArrayList<String>


                            var myDataset = ArrayList<String>()
                            myDataset.add("1")
                            myDataset.add("2")
                            myDataset.add("3")
// Decided to just test with dummydata for now till I can see it

                            val test = Fragment2.MyAdapter(myDataset)

//Accidently didn't remove this part, but was trying this along with some other code I got rid of to test fragment2, didn't work though.


                            val sitespref: SharedPreferences = getSharedPreferences(LAST_SITES, PRIVATE_MODE)


                            val editor3 = sitespref.edit()

                            editor3.clear()
                            editor3.putString("sites",output)
                            editor3.apply()

//Tried using getsharedpreferences, saving the content then loading it on the otherside, as expected though it just loads up from the last time I did this so results are outdated.


                            mResultTextView = findViewById(R.id.result_textview)



                            findViewById<TextView>(R.id.catchsitevariable).text = parts[0]

// Was just a test to see if I could override it the same way as the others - catchsitevariable is a textview in my recyclerview on the viewpager fragment






                        }
                    }
                }

    }
```

MyViewPagerAdapter - still on MainActivity, works correctly but figured Id include it just in case since it's relevent

```
    class MyViewPagerAdapter(manager: FragmentManager) : FragmentPagerAdapter(manager){

        private val fragmentList : MutableList<Fragment> = ArrayList()
        private val titleList : MutableList<String> = ArrayList()

        override fun getItem(position: Int): Fragment {
            return fragmentList[position]
        }

        override fun getCount(): Int {
            return fragmentList.size
        }

        fun addFragment(fragment: Fragment,title:String){
            fragmentList.add(fragment)
            titleList.add(title)
        }

        override fun getPageTitle(position: Int): CharSequence? {
            return titleList[position]
        }

    }
```

Fragment 2: Oncreateview / onviewCreated

```
    override fun onCreateView(inflater: LayoutInflater, container: ViewGroup?,
                              savedInstanceState: Bundle?): View? {

        val name = arguments?.getString(ARG_NAME)


               return inflater.inflate(R.layout.page2fragment, container, false)

    }

    override fun onViewCreated(view: View, savedInstanceState: Bundle?) {

        var recyclerView: RecyclerView = view.findViewById<RecyclerView>(R.id.recyclesites)

var myDataset = ArrayList<String>()


        val sharedPref: SharedPreferences = this.activity!!.getSharedPreferences(PREF_NAME, PRIVATE_MODE)

        val username = sharedPref.getString("user", "Not logged in")

        val sites: SharedPreferences = this.activity!!.getSharedPreferences(LAST_SITES, PRIVATE_MODE)

        val output = sites.getString("sites","")

        println("output is $output")

// Was using this to test saving it, if nothing saved just comes out "output is" otherwise comes out with the previous result, this is getting called before the Async request in MainActivity is done.

        val delimiter = ","

        val parts = output.split(delimiter)

        viewManager = LinearLayoutManager(getActivity())
        viewAdapter = MyAdapter(myDataset)

        recyclerView = view.findViewById<RecyclerView>(R.id.recyclesites).apply {
            setHasFixedSize(true)

            layoutManager = viewManager

            val adapter = MyAdapter(myDataset)
            adapter.replaceItems(myDataset)
            adapter.getItemCount()
            adapter.testing(findViewById<RecyclerView>(R.id.recyclesites))
            recyclerView.adapter = adapter


        }

    }
```

MyAdapter - on fragment2, used for the recycleview

```
    class MyAdapter(private val myDataset: ArrayList<String>) :
            RecyclerView.Adapter<MyAdapter.MyViewHolder>() {

        private var items = ArrayList<String>()

        class MyViewHolder(val textView: RelativeLayout) : RecyclerView.ViewHolder(textView)


        override fun onCreateViewHolder(parent: ViewGroup,
                                        viewType: Int): MyAdapter.MyViewHolder {

            val textView = LayoutInflater.from(parent.context)
                    .inflate(R.layout.recyclesites, parent, false) as RelativeLayout
            return MyViewHolder(textView)
        }
        fun replaceItems(items: ArrayList<String>) {
            this.items = items
            notifyDataSetChanged()
        }
        override fun onBindViewHolder(holder: MyViewHolder, position: Int) {
            holder.textView.text = myDataset[position]
        }

        fun testing(parent: ViewGroup): MyAdapter.MyViewHolder{
            val textView = LayoutInflater.from(parent.context)
                    .inflate(R.layout.recyclesites, parent, false) as RelativeLayout
            return MyViewHolder(textView)

//Effectivelly what I used to inflate the actual inner parts of the recyclerview

        }
        // Return the size of your dataset (invoked by the layout manager)
        override fun getItemCount(): Int{
            println(myDataset.size)
// Was coming out 0 for most attempts when trying to send the data across.

            return myDataset.size
        }
    }
```

Fairly new to both Stackoverflow and Kotlin, let me know if there's anything I missed.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: hello, I am trying to understand your problem here. you want to do an async call in the main activity before populating fragment 2?

Comment: Hi Miriana, To be honest my idea would be either to do as you said and do the async call before populating fragment 2, or to update fragment 2 after the async function is done, wasn't quite sure which would be more suitable, so long as the data is able to get there in a reasonable way though I can do whatever is suggested

Comment: why don't you do the async call inside the fragment itself?

Comment: Tried that, but effectivelly when I did it it only called when I went to view it, so essensially when I swiped to the fragments part of the viewpager the recyclerview was blank until I tried to swipe back to the original fragment at which point it would fill up, this only worked after a few seconds though and sometimes wouldn't happen at all I found, so I moved on from trying that.

Comment: the best approach is actually to have it in the fragment itself and put a loader in the second fragment that takes the full screen some sort of a gif. In that way, you will avoid the empty page. Then when the result of asyncall is retreived, dismiss the loader and populate the recyclerview.

Answer (score 0):

The first approach should be call API from the second fragment itself.

Set your ViewPager's setOffscreenPageLimit to 1 so it would load the second fragment as well and check the Fragment lifecycle to see where your API call fit batter.

onCreateView() of second fragment. Once the API call back given result bind it to View.

You can also think about this where you will get an event when user change pagehttps://developer.android.com/reference/android/support/v4/view/ViewPager.SimpleOnPageChangeListener.html#onPageSelected(int). Once the page position is 1 then you can call API if data is not available.